# Can't grant roles with GRANT OPTION privilege

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB database with a few roles. For simplicity let's assume I have a `admins` role. It was created by the `root` user with the commands below:

```
CREATE ROLE admins;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO admins WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I also have another role `default` which does not have any privileges.
I granted the `admins` role to a user `myuser` (again with `root`):

```
CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY 'mysuperstrongpassword';
GRANT admins TO myuser;
```

With that in mind I logged into a session using the `myuser` account, activated the `admins` role and created a new user `newuser`. However when I try to grant the `default` role to `newuser` with

```
GRANT default TO newuser;
```

I get hit with a `Access denied to user 'myuser'@'%'`. As of my understanding of the `GRANT OPTION` privilege, the grantee should have the permission to grant any privileges. Is there a different privilege required to allow setting roles?

I have found some information regarding the `ADMIN OPTION` privilege, however have not been able to grant it to a user or role with

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO [role|user] WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

I haven't been able to verify if the `ADMIN OPTION` even exists for my version.

Current MariaDB version is 10.11.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few problems listed, so do comment if I missed any.

A [role granted to a user isn't default](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/roles_overview/). It can be set with [SET DEFAULT ROLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-default-role/) like:

```
SET DEFAULT ROLE admin FOR myuser
```

Note a user can only have one default role. Use [SET ROLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-role/) to switch to an explicit role if you have it:

```
SET ROLE admin
```

On your `default` role, if you want all users to have a base set of privileges, use the `TO PUBLIC` syntax ([ref](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#to-public)):

```
GRANT SELECT ON common_db.* TO PUBLIC
```

Granting `ADMIN OPTION` isn't a privilege, so it has [explicit syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#roles) (that doesn't use `PRIVILEGE`):

```
GRANT admin ON [role|user] WITH ADMIN OPTION

GRANT default ON myuser WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

Comment: `SET ROLE` wasn't the issue. I tried to describe this in my questions when I said 'I activated the `admins` role...'. However the rest, especially the explanation and link for the `ADMIN OPTION` syntax were spot on. Works like a charm. 
I still find it a bit unintuitive, that `GRANT OPTION` does not give the grantee the power to grant roles.
Either way, question closed.
(Kindly upvote the question so other people with the same problem have a better chance finding a solution than me)

Comment: The implementation closely followed the SQL standard hence normal mariadb thinks like `GRANT OPTION` aren't the same.